# HRA exemption ITR India

Tags: taxes, income-tax, india

I want to explore the HRA exemption option to optimise my tax.

Currently I stay in Pune ( Non Metro city ) in India in a rented flat with my non working senior citizen mother.

Rent a flat at 45K per month which gets me exemption of 3.5L

I was assessing to see if I can get the rent agreement done between my mother and Owner for 45K rent and my mother sublet me the flat for 1Lakh rent. I any way transfer the money to her.

By doing so I can increase my HRA exemption to around 8L.

Question-

1. Is it allowed to sublet a property at an higher rent?
2. Can the rent agreement state that tenant can only sublet to a family member? So that the owner is also not concerned?
3. Will there be any extra tax implication for the owner?